# How to get previous <li> when the li's are wrapped inside <ol>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i get the previous li when it is wrapped inside an ol?

I have used the following script, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".categoryitem").click(function () {
        alert("hihi");
        $(this).parent().prev("li").css('background-color', 'red');
        $(this).prev("li").css('background-color', 'red');       
    });
});
</script>
```

This is how the HTML looks like (In my real application i have set the class name on each li, but didnt do it in this example)

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="">Item 1</a>
</li>
<ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 1.1</a>
</li>
</ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 2</a>
</li>
<ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 2.1</a>
</li>
<ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 2.1.1</a>
</li>
</ol>
<ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 2.1.2</a>
</li>
</ol>
<ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 2.1.3</a>
</li>
</ol>
<ol>
<li>
<a href="">Item 2.1.4</a>
</li>
</ol>
</ol>
</ul>
```

When i click on Item 1.1, the parent 1 becomes red
When i click on item 2, nothing happens, but i would like 1.1 to become red
When i click on items 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4 nothing happens
When i click on item 2.1, the parent 2 becomes red

I would like all previous LI's to become red, even if they are in higher levels

What am i doing wrong?

This is the method that creates the tree:
**EDIT: I changed ol to ul, for each group**

```
<ul>
@{
    foreach(var cq in Model) {
        @ShowSubItems(cq);
    }
}
</ul>

@helper ShowSubItems(MvcApplication3.Models.ViewModels.Category.AllQuestionsInCategoriesViewModel MyObj)
    {

    <li class="categoryitem" categoryid="1">@Html.ActionLink(MyObj.Category_Number + " " + MyObj.Category_Name, "DisplayQuestions", new { categoryId = MyObj.Category_ID, page = 1 })</li>



        if (MyObj.SubCategories != null && MyObj.SubCategories.Count != 0)
        {
<ul>
            @foreach (var subitem in MyObj.SubCategories)
            {

            @ShowSubItems(subitem)

            }
</ul>
        }
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. You can't have OL's directly inside UL's. The children of UL's have to be LI's.

Comment: In addition to what @ŠimeVidas said, the browsers will most likely correct this HTML so the structure you wrote down is not the same the browser creates.

Comment: unrelated: don't you think that wrapping each `li` with `ol` is too much? the whole point of `ol` is to group a set of `li`'s together.

Comment: It might be incorrect, but it displays it how it is supposed so. Can you show me the alternative? I have edited my question to show you the method that creates the tree

Comment: it might be displayed correct, but the browser might autocorrect something (and each browser might do something else) which can lead to the problem that your js wont work even if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for poiting out that my HTML was incorrect. I have changed it as you can see in the example. The function works now, except that if i am in a top level, i would like it to paint the lowest li of the previous top-level red (which is outside of the current ul), how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the CLOSEST PARENT, you can simply use .closest()

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme">Click Me!</a>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.clickme').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle source of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/y36qg/

Comment: I would like to paint the previous closest <li> red. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The example posted by me does the following: when a user clicks on the "clickme" link, jQuery makes the background of the previous closest li ( containing the clicked element ) red. If you want to "paint" it red I assume my answer is correct. Anyway, be more specific if you want something else

Comment: Understood the question. You mean, the previous <li> also outbounding the current <ul>. Wait 5 minutes, I'm writing a snippet.